# GPU out of memory when starting training of nnUNet

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, jupyter-lab

It's strange because I already trained several models using nnUNet, and now suddenly i get this error before it starts the first epoch.
The complete error is:

"""

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/bin/nnUNet_train", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnunet/run/run_training.py", line 179, in main
    trainer.run_training()
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnunet/training/network_training/nnUNetTrainerV2.py", line 440, in run_training
    ret = super().run_training()
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnunet/training/network_training/nnUNetTrainer.py", line 317, in run_training
    super(nnUNetTrainer, self).run_training()
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnunet/training/network_training/network_trainer.py", line 464, in run_training
    l = self.run_iteration(self.tr_gen, True)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnunet/training/network_training/nnUNetTrainerV2.py", line 247, in run_iteration
    output = self.network(data)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnunet/network_architecture/generic_UNet.py", line 391, in forward
    x = self.conv_blocks_context[d](x)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnunet/network_architecture/generic_UNet.py", line 142, in forward
    return self.blocks(x)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 141, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnunet/network_architecture/generic_UNet.py", line 68, in forward
    return self.lrelu(self.instnorm(x))
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/instancenorm.py", line 72, in forward
    return self._apply_instance_norm(input)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/instancenorm.py", line 32, in _apply_instance_norm
    return F.instance_norm(
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2466, in instance_norm
    return torch.instance_norm(
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.78 GiB total capacity; 1.71 GiB already allocated; 6.50 MiB free; 1.73 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/batchgenerators/dataloading/multi_threaded_augmenter.py", line 92, in results_loop
    raise RuntimeError("Abort event was set. So someone died and we should end this madness. \nIMPORTANT: "
RuntimeError: Abort event was set. So someone died and we should end this madness. 
IMPORTANT: This is not the actual error message! Look further up to see what caused the error. Please also check whether your RAM was full
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/viberti/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/batchgenerators/dataloading/multi_threaded_augmenter.py", line 92, in results_loop
    raise RuntimeError("Abort event was set. So someone died and we should end this madness. \nIMPORTANT: "
RuntimeError: Abort event was set. So someone died and we should end this madness. 
IMPORTANT: This is not the actual error message! Look further up to see what caused the error. Please also check whether your RAM was full
```

"""

I am working in Jupyter Lab, and using a Tesla V1 GPU.
It doesn't make sense to reduce batch size like many sugget in similar situztions, because nnUNet automatically adapts it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

or reload notebook

Comment: I tried both of them but with no results